# two apps almost identical, only one registers info in my database. Why?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to figure out why one app, App 1, saves data into my database, while App 2, doesn't.

Android App 1 and App 2 are exactly the same, apart from 1 line in this activity :

**App 1 :**

```
package com.example.chris.loginregister;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Chris on 24/07/2016.
 */

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://tom.comxa.com/Register.php";

    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String username, Response.Listener<String> listener){

        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {

        return params;
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://tom.comxa.com/Register.php";
```

I have in App 2 :

```
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://12.345.67.89/Register.php";
```

Both apps pass the exact same test I have in another activity a `System.out.println` exercise :

```
//when the Register button is clicked :
public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("first step of the test, at least my button is recognised");

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
//                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("second step, recognises my JSON");
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
//                            System.out.println("yes, succeeded, it works, it recognises my PHP file");

                            if (success) {
                                System.out.println("yes, succeeded, it works, it recognises my PHP file");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                            } else {
                                System.out.println("no, failed, but at least it recognises my JSON");
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("no, failed utterly");
                        }

                        System.out.println("json response: " + response);
                    }
                };
```

My logcat for both apps is exactly the same, when I click the 'Register button:

```
08-20 00:19:16.770 30244-30244/com.example.chris.loginregister I/System.out: first step of the test, at least my button is recognised
08-20 00:19:16.770 30244-30244/com.example.chris.loginregister I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Lcom/android/volley/Request;.finish (Ljava/lang/String;)V from Lcom/example/chris/loginregister/RegisterRequest;)
08-20 00:19:16.770 30244-30244/com.example.chris.loginregister I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.android.volley.Request.finish, referenced from method com.example.chris.loginregister.RegisterRequest.access$super
08-20 00:19:16.770 30244-30244/com.example.chris.loginregister W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17084: Lcom/android/volley/Request;.finish (Ljava/lang/String;)V
08-20 00:19:16.770 30244-30244/com.example.chris.loginregister D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00c8
08-20 00:19:17.290 30244-30244/com.example.chris.loginregister I/System.out: yes, succeeded, it works, it recognises my PHP file
08-20 00:19:17.510 30244-30244/com.example.chris.loginregister I/System.out: json response: {"success":true}
```

Yet only App 1 actually saves the details into my mysql database, at tom.comxa.com.

Any idea why?

My register.php files are a bit different too, just one line:

**App 1:**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("webhost", "user", "password", "a7720716_data");
```

App 2:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("webhost2", "root", "password", "mydatabasename");
```

Comment: Please don't post credentials to the internet for everyone to see.

Comment: These two files differ considerably in what they connect to. That does seem to be a big deal.

Comment: @tadman The credentials aren't real. As for these two files differ considerably in what they connect to... yes, they are two different IP addresses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My php file was of the form

```
$con = mysqli_connect("12.345.67.89", "root", "password", "mydatabasename");
```

changed it to :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "mydatabasename");
```

and it worked.